# Frame Layout Different on different screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, android-framelayout

I'm having a major problem.  The same .xml works fine on a larger screen but not on a smaller screen. The problem occurs on both the emulator and on real phones. Here's my .XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="CLOSED"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="123sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="CLOSED"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="193dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="CLOSED"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="263dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="CLOSED"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And here are the screenshots for the different sized screens. Basically, i've written a code that covers up the '0' on the graph with the 'closed' text views.  Works fine on the larger screen but on smaller ones, all of the TextViews are bunched up in the corner.  I've already tried layout-small, layout, and layout-large .xmls. Nothing seems to work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!!

I had to set the layout gravity first on the TextVeiws, then it started working.  It's weird that it worked on the larger screens without the gravity attribute specified.